Are HttpRequestOptions sent as part of request to endpoint?
I have decided to make use of System.Net.Http.HttpRequestOptions to pass around some context between an instance of HTTPClientHandler and the class that's using the HttpClient.
My only query is if HttpRequestOptions are somehow included in the request when the request is sent to the endpoint, or are they strictly handled on client side**?**
Microsoft's documentation is bare bones and has no useful information at all.
Update: For what it's worth, I asked CoPilot if they are sent and it said No. I asked ChatGPT the same thing and it said yes. So these guys are not to be relied on as always.

Start/ install a packet sniffing tool like WireShark and check

@MindSwipe yeh, might try that. Thanks
